# Find mathmls from a String using java

Tags: java, regex, mathml

I have a Big string which has multiple mathmls in it. Want to take out all of them in a string array. Using regex to find them. But something missing in the regex so it doesn't gives any output.

What is the regex for MathMls?

Example string

> **Find sum of** «math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\"»«mroot»«mrow»«mi»#«/mi»«mi»a«/mi»«/mrow»«mn»3«/mn»«/mroot»«mo»=«/mo»«mroot»«mrow»«mi»#«/mi»«mi»b«/mi»«/mrow»«mn»3«/mn»«/mroot»«/math»        **and**         «math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\"»«mo»=«/mo»«msup»«mfenced»«mrow»«mi»#«/mi»«mi»b«/mi»«/mrow»«/mfenced»«mfrac»«mn»1«/mn»«mn»3«/mn»«/mfrac»«/msup»«/math»

From this get 2 mathmls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with Java's regex engine since this is valid input:

```
<math>
  <apply>
    <plus/>
    <apply>
      <times/>
      <ci>a</ci>
      <apply>
        <power/>
        <ci>x</ci>
        <cn>2</cn>
      </apply>
    </apply>
    <apply>
      <times/>
      <ci>b</ci>
      <ci>x</ci>
    </apply>
    <ci>c</ci>
  </apply>
</math>
```

i.e.: there can be arbitrary nested tags and Java's regex engine has no ability to match recursive patterns. You will have to resort to [some parser](http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/javadoc/be/ugent/caagt/jmathtex/mathml/MathMLParser.html) to handle MathML input.

### EDIT

> Can i consider the entire thing as a string and find for a pattern which matches  ? That is what i am trying. And there is not going to be any recursive  tags inside another  tag. they will be in same level.

In that case, try this pattern:

```
<math[>\s](?s).*?</math>
```

or as a String literal:

```
"<math[>\\s](?s).*?</math>"
```

which means:

```
<math[>\s]   # match `<math` followed by a space or `>`
(?s).*?      # reluctantly match zero or more chars (`(?s)` causes `\r` 
             # and `\n` also to be matched)
</math>      # match `</math>`
```

Comment: Can i consider the entire thing as a string and find for a pattern which matches <math .* /math> ? That is what i am trying. And there is not going to be any recursive <math> tags inside another <math> tag. they will be in same level.

Comment: Super.. "<math[>\\s](?s).*?</math>" did it. Thanks